# Converting Variadic template pack into std::initializer_list

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, initializer-list

Assume that there is a function which accepts several strings:

```
void fun (const std::initializer_list<std::string>& strings) {
  for(auto s : strings)
    // do something
}
```

Now, I have a variadic `template` function say `foo()` as:

```
template<typename ...Args>
void foo () {
  fun(???);
}
```

This method is called externally as:

```
foo<A, B, C, D>(); // where A, B, C, D are classes
```

And these classes which are passed as arguments are expected to contain a common `static const` member:

```
static const std::string value = "...";
```

Here are my questions (how to):

1. When inside `foo()`, check if all the `Args` contain `value` using
   `static_assert`
2. Pass all such values to `fun()` to form an `initializer_list`; e.g.
   `fun({A::value, B::value, ...});`

Searched several threads related to variadic templates and its unpacking but I am still novice in this area. Explanation in little more detail is much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As for the second question, just do it this way:

```
template<typename ...Args>
void foo () {
  fun({Args::value...});
}
```

The mechanism is pretty intuitive: you create an initalizer list that contains the expanded `Args::value` pattern, thus resolving (in your case) to `{ A::value, B::value, C::value, D::value }`.

Here is a complete program:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void fun (const std::initializer_list<std::string>& strings) {
    for(auto s : strings)
    {
        std::cout << s << " ";
    }
}

template<typename ...Args>
void foo () {
  fun({Args::value...});
}

struct A { static std::string value; };
struct B { static std::string value; };
struct C { static std::string value; };
struct D { static std::string value; };

std::string A::value = "Hello";
std::string B::value = "World";
std::string C::value = "of";
std::string D::value = "Variadic Templates";

int main()
{
    foo<A, B, C, D>(); // where A, B, C, D are classes
}
```

And here is a [**live example**](http://ideone.com/PiuAVC).

As for the static assertion, you may write a type trait that determines whether a certain type has a member variable `value`:

```
template<typename T, typename V = bool>
struct has_value : std::false_type { };

template<typename T>
struct has_value<T,
    typename std::enable_if<
        !std::is_same<decltype(std::declval<T>().value), void>::value,
        bool
        >::type
    > : std::true_type
{
    typedef decltype(std::declval<T>().value) type;
};
```

Then, you could use it this way:

```
template<typename T>
struct check_has_value
{
    static_assert(has_value<T>::value, "!");
};

template<typename ...Args>
void foo () {
    auto l = { (check_has_value<Args>(), 0)... };
    fun({Args::value...});
}
```

Here is a [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=77063275dc772ae05e430272a2c9f444-ff683aff19d685e086e79e4ef634f9fb) of a successful check (all classes has a `value` data member). Here is a [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=c243ba5fd149f463d8a0355a1cf3802e-ff683aff19d685e086e79e4ef634f9fb) of an unsuccessful check (class `D`'s data member is called `values`)

Answer (score 3):

The second part is easier:

```
template<typename ...Args>
void foo () {
   fun({Args::value...});
}
```

The first part is tricky, because `static_assert` is a declaration, not an expression, so you'd have to expand the variadic pack within the first parameter.  It may be easier just to let the call to `fun` do the checking for you.  Here's a sketch of how to do it with an auxiliary `all` `constexpr` function:

```
constexpr bool all() { return true; }
template<typename... Args> constexpr bool all(bool first, Args&&... rest) {
   return first && all(rest...);
}

template<typename ...Args>
void foo () {
   static_assert(all(std::is_convertible<decltype(Args::value),
      std::string>::value...), "All Args must have a value");
   fun({Args::value...});
}
```

Comment: Oh So easy .. you are right about `fun()` doing the part; just wanted to save myself from the bad compiler errors. :)

Comment: How is this checking if all `Args...` has a `value` member?

Comment: @0x499602D2 note the pack expansion inside the call to `all()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer to both points:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

void fun (const std::initializer_list<std::string>& strings) {
  for(auto s : strings)
    cout << s << endl;
}

// This uses SFINAE to find if there's a string T::value in T
template <typename T>
struct HasValue
{
    typedef char OK; //sizeof() guaranteed 1
    struct BAD { char x[2]; }; //sizeof() guaranteed >1

    template <const string *>
    struct Helper;

    template <typename X>
    static OK has(X*, Helper<&X::value>* = nullptr); //SF if &X::value is not a const string*

    static BAD has(...);  //will be picked in SF case

    static const bool value = (sizeof(has((T*)nullptr)) == sizeof(OK));
};


// This template (and its specialisation) ensure all args have ::value
template <typename H, typename... T>
struct HaveValue : public integral_constant<bool, HasValue<H>::value && HaveValue<T...>::value>
{};

template <typename H>
struct HaveValue<H> : public HasValue<H>
{};



template <typename... Args>
void foo() {
    static_assert(HaveValue<Args...>::value, "All arguments must have const string ::value");
    fun({Args::value...});  //answer to point 2: create the initialiser list
}

// Example data follow
struct A
{
    static const string value;
};
const string A::value = "AA";

struct B
{
    static const string value;
};
const string B::value = "BB";

struct C{};

int main()
{
    foo<A, B>();
    //foo<A, B, C>();  //uncomment to have the static assertion fire
}
```

[See it live](http://ideone.com/5rPfQd).