# variadic template with function(args)... expansion

Tags: c++11, c++14, variadic-templates, initializer-list, variadic

Today, my colleague showed me an amazing c++ expansion trick by varadic template with function calls. In succinct, it looks like:

```
template <typename T, T... I>
void print_sequence(std::integer_sequence<T, I...>) {
    std::initializer_list<bool>{ bool(std::cout << I << ' ')... };
}
```

Then I find something similar from [wiki/Variadic_template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template), and stackoverflow [Unpacking a typelist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42002126/unpacking-a-typelist) e.g,

```
  template<typename... Args> inline void pass(Args&&...) {}
  template<typename... Args> inline void expand(Args&&... args) {
    pass( some_function(args)... );
  }
  expand(42, "answer", true);
```

i really struggle with this style `some_function(args)...`, even by reading the above wiki link. How does this work? and why it has to be non-void return type? does it solely work with function or any kind of applicable expression? e.g., from another stackoverflow post [Converting Variadic template pack into std::initializer_list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16478089/converting-variadic-template-pack-into-stdinitializer-list)

```
template<typename ...Args>
void foo () {
  fun({Args::value...});
}
```

is the above `...` binding with `Args::value` the same context as the one with function calls?